# Elementary os 6 odin installation - no partitions shown after getting current configuration

Tags: uefi, install, dell

I have a different problem while installing EOS 6 Odin in my Dell Inspiron with UEFI boot.

Initially I had issue with boot with the previous ISO download. But when I downloaded August 23rd IOS file and created new bootable USB using Etcher as suggested in the official website, the issue of boot went away and I am able to see the demo (Try Demo).

But when I tried to install it alongside Windows 10 (with 463GB of space available for EOS), after I chose the language and keyboard, it tries to fetch the current partitions (Getting current configuration) but after couple of seconds the spinner disappears and does not show anything in the screen; I cannot see any existing partitions and Next button (the other button to proceed the installation) remains disabled.

But I can see the Modify Partitions button at the bottom left corner of the screen and can create the partitions as well. Even after creating partitions, I cannot see the partitions.

Anyone facing the issues or what could be the issue !

Comment: There are two things that might cause this issue: (1) “Fast boot” is enabled in the UEFI (2) Windows was “Restarted” then booted off the USB instead of “Shut Down” then boot from USB. When Windows shuts down it will sometimes do something like a “hibernate” action, which leaves the partitions in an open state, making it unsafe for any other OS to modify the storage device (or risk data corruption).

Comment: In any case, I did not find a work around to move forward and not able to install it. I think I will have to switch to something else now which I didn't want to.